# Cheap hash of three inputs independent of their order

Tags: hash, vhdl, fpga, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

I have a module that takes three inputs, each of which is three bits wide.

```
output = f(inputA, inputB, inputC)
```

The output depends on the values of the three inputs but does not depend on their order.

i.e. `f(inputA, inputB, inputC) = f(inputB, inputC, inputA)`

The solution should work well for both FPGAs and ASICs.  Currently I am implementing it without taking advantage of the symmetry, but I assume that explicitly forcing the synthesizer to consider the symmetry will result in a better implementation.

I am planning on implementing this using a hash, h, of the three inputs that does not depend on their order.  I can then do:

```
hash <= h(inputA, inputB, inputC);

output <= VALUE0 when hash = 0 else
          VALUE1 when hash = 1 else
          .....
```

*My question is what should I use for the hash function?*

**My thoughts so far:**

If each input is 3 bits wide there are 512 possibilities, but only 120 when you consider the symmetry, so theoretically I should be able to use a hash that is 7 bits wide.  Practically it may need to be longer.

Each bit of the hash is a function of the input bits and must respect the symmetry of the three inputs.  The bits of the hash should be independent from one another.  But I'm not sure how to generate these functions.

Comment: Also, I have tried using a sort function as a hash where it returns the inputs sorted in ascending order and concatenated, however this operation was too expensive and almost negated the advantage of being able to use a smaller lookup table.

Comment: A straight-forward suggestion would be to use `hash = a xor b xor c`, but that is of course only 3 bits wide - I don't know if that's good enough for your purpose.

Comment: I need unique hashs which means the hash must be at least 7 bits long.   But yes, it would certainly make sense for those to be three of the bits.

Comment: I have a feeling that the function required to achieve a dense hash like that would, itself, require a 512 entry lookup table. If you're planning on saving a lot of the inputs in a delay line or something, that might be fair, but I don't think it will save you much if it goes directly to a function lookup. I'd bet that your synthesis tool is already analyzing your function's solution space (equal to or less than 120 unique outputs) to get an efficient implementation. Depending on what it does, it might be able to be optimized (automatically) by more than just symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in your question, you could sort and **concatenate your inputs**.

**In pseudo code:**

```
if (A < B)
    swap(A, B);
if (B < C)
    swap(B, C);
if (A < B)
    swap(A, B);
```

**As block diagram:**

[image]

The 6-in/6-out function needed for a "conditional swap" block:

```
A3x = A3 B3 ;
A2x = A3 B3' B2  + A3' A2 B3  + A2 B2 ;
A1x = A2 B3' B2' B1 + A3' A2' A1 B2  + A3 A2 B2' B1 
    + A2' A1 B3 B2  + A3 B3' B1 + A3' A1 B3  + A1 B1;
B3x = B3  + A3 ;
B2x = A3' B2  + A2 B3'  + B3 B2  + A3 A2 ;
B1x = A3' A2' B1 + A1 B3' B2'  + A2' B3 B1 + A3 A1 B2'  
    + A3' B2 B1 + A2 A1 B3'  + A3' B3 B1 + A3 A1 B3'  
    + B3 B2 B1 + A3 A2 A1 ;
```

I have to admit that this solution is not exactly "cheap" and results in a 9-bit hash rather than in a 7-bit hash. Therefore, a look-up table might in fact be the best solution.